# System.Threading.Timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

When we use System.Threading.Timer, then is the method executed on the thread that created the timer? Or is ir executed in another thread?

```
class Timer
{
    static void Main()
    {
        TimerCallback tcall = statusChecker.CheckStatus;
        Timer stateTimer = new Timer(tcb, autoEvent, 1000, 250);
    }
}
class StatusChecker
{
    public void CheckStatus(Object stateInfo)
    {
    }
}
```

My question is if the method called by the timer delegate (`CheckStatus`) is executed in main thread or is it executed in another thread?

Comment: It is rather ambiguous what are you trying to ask here - can you please post some code to clarify your question?

Answer (score 6):

`System.Threading.Timer` will execute its work on another thread in the thread pool.

`System.Windows.Forms.Timer` will execute on the existing (GUI) thread.

Comment: Also to be noted - the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` will revert to a threadpool thread if there are no active forms (like a console app). And the method will get executed when the thread would be otherwise idle (no event handlers executing). But you aren't spending much time in event handlers anyway, right? :)

Comment: @Vilx - I didn't know that, so thanks for the additional comment on my answer :)

Comment: Actually... I take it back. It doesn't revert. It's only usable in Windows Forms. But I'm sure I once (not too long ago) saw one of the standard timers that chose among windows forms or threadpool thread... can't find it now though. :(

Comment: Oh, wait, now I remember - that was BackgroundWorker! :) Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 2):

The docs say the following:

> The method specified for callback should be reentrant, because it is called on ThreadPool threads.

So the callback will almost certainly be on another thread.

Of course, if you launch the timer from a ThreadPool thread, there's a chance it might execute on the same thread, but no guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

MSDN States:

> Use a `TimerCallback` delegate to specify the method you want the `Timer` to execute. The timer delegate is specified when the timer is constructed, and cannot be changed. The method does not execute on the thread that created the timer; it executes on a `ThreadPool` thread supplied by the system.

Hence, in your example, timer delegate `(CheckStatus)` would be executed in an seperate thread.